# Taxonomy term View: How to NAVIGATE the pages with "Exposed filter"?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, uri

My problem is this:
I am trying to add EXPOSED FILTERS in the DEFAULT TAXONOMY VIEW.
I just clicked on ADD in FILTER CRITERIA. I added a couple of exposed filters . Apparently they work. So I can visualize them in the page.
example:

```
name_of_website.com/name_of_taxonomy/name_of_term_1
```

but from there if I use the EXPOSED FILTER and in the EXPOSED FILTER I want to change Content Type or Term I can't do that because the new URL generated will be:

```
name_of_website.com/name_of_taxonomy/name_of_term_1?type=All&...
```

To make it that works it should be:

```
name_of_website.com/explore/?type=All&field_year_value=All&fi...
```

The page "**explore**"
is the page where there is a VIEW that takes ALL the 
content of the content that I've created before (and also there I added the EXPOSED FILTERS).

I hope I've explained clearly and I hope someone can help me.
Thank you very much for your work and support.
Gilles